# Out of Memory Error - Java Heap Space while writing to Excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a data of almost 100,000 records and I am trying to write the data to `.xlsx` file using `XSSFWorkbook` through Java code. I am able to fetch all the data from database to an `ArrayList`. By iterating the `ArryList`, I am writing the data to `.xlsx` file cell by cell. 
As it reaches to 8000 rows, java code throws `Out of Memory Heap Space` Error.

I have read somewhere that `SXSSFWorkbook` will be lighter when compared to `XSSFWorkbook`, so I tried using `SXSSFWorkbook`. But still I am facing the same problem.

So is there anything that I am missing with the Workbooks or with my Java Code??

Initially, when I have 60,000 records data, I had used `.xls` file. The same java code is able to generate the `.xls` file with `HSSFWorkbook`.

Increasing the Java Heap Space is not at all an option as my data will be increased tremendously in future.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Small piece of code, the way I am writing the data to Excel.

```
int rowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();

Row lastRow = null ;

Cell cell = null;

ReportingHelperVo reportingHelperVo = null; 

for (ReportingVo reportingVo : reportingVos) {

rowNum++;

lastRow = sheet.createRow(rowNum);

reportingHelperVo = reportingVo.reportingHelperVo;

cell = lastRow.createCell(0);

cell.setCellValue(reportingHelperVo.getLocation());

cell.setCellStyle(style);

cell = lastRow.createCell(1);

cell.setCellValue(reportingHelperVo.getCity());

cell.setCellStyle(style);

cell = lastRow.createCell(2);

cell.setCellValue(reportingHelperVo.getCountry());

cell.setCellStyle(style);

}
```

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup 100,000 in South Asian numbering system

Comment: okay, that is nice :) But don't expect someone outside South Asia to know it.

Comment: @SatelliteSD I'm not the OP; I had to look it up myself :)

Comment: relevant bits of your code would be helpful here...

Comment: When is OOM thrown by JMV in case you use SXSSFWorkbook?

Comment: @Taky when I am writing the data into the Excel. When the controller reaches 10000. OOM..!!

Answer (score 12):

`SXSSFWorkbook` is not like light weight,but there is a advantage with this.

If you declare as

```
SXSSFWorkbook workbook= new SXSSFWorkbook(200);
```

then for every 200 rows written on the workbook, memory will be flushed to diskspace so there will be no burden in heapspace.

Answer (score 6):

[XSSFWorkbook](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html) - creates an object representation for all Excel documents (should work like DOM).

[SXSSFWorkbook](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html) - should require constant memory. When is OOM thrown by JMV? What type of [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) did you use? Try to use [FORWARD_ONLY](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY) to restrict caching data by JDBC driver retrieved from DB.

BTW best weay to fix OutOfMemoryError is to analyze heap dump. 
Use -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError parameter and [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to understand how your application works.

Comment: I am not using JDBC for retrieving data. I am using Hibernate and I am fetching the data into an ArrayList. And I need to look into XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError parameter and MAT for better understanding. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Are you sure you application will not throw OOM when data size growth? Try to research http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#doWork(org.hibernate.jdbc.Work) to work with JDBC directly and tune FetchSize and ResultSetType.

Comment: I am sure that JVM will throw OOM as the data size grows. Thats where I wanna optimize my code so that JVM will have a sufficient free heap memory every time. Thanks for you link. I will try and check with my code .

Answer (score 2):

> I am writing the data to .xlsx file cell by cell. As it reaches to
>   8000 rows, java code throws Out of Memory Heap Space Error.

Re-use exsiting java objects, instead of creating `new` ones each iteration.

And/or use a csv file instead of excel.

Comment: I have macros enabled functions in the Excel which are related to the data written in the sheets. So I am not sure, CSV file will support Macros. On the other hand, my client is expecting an Excel report

Comment: post the code where you loop through and create the rows. re use the java objects that temporarily holdd te values

Answer (score 1):

```
Workbook workBook = new SXSSFWorkbook();
```

You can export more than 1 lakh (100000) records.

Comment: No dude.. Right now I have 50,000 records. But still SXSSFWorkbook is not supporting. At 15,000 records itself.. OOM..!

Comment: if u are using any where autosize column or some styles in loops avoid them.they may also cause.

Comment: Yes I am using styles for border of the cells in loop. But I cant avoid them.. :( And what is Autosize column? Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Dont create this in loop  HSSFCellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();U can declare then out side and pass them to the corresponding method.

Comment: For me ,when I changed from XSSFWorkbook to SXSSFWorkbook, it really works

Answer (score 0):

Page results from the database rather than reading them all in one go.

Comment: I am fetching the data from database as a small chunks (5000 records) and then I am writing the data to Excel and again I am fetching another 5000 records and appending it to the existing Excel. But still, when it is writing at 15,000 records, java code is throwing OOM error.

Comment: How big is your heap size? I know you say you can't increase it, but what are the numbers you're playing with? Excel files are extremely verbose in memory footprint and it may simply be that you don't have enough. If you create a dummy Excel sheet with the amount of rows you're expecting are you able to read it in using the API or does that also throw OOM?

Comment: My Apache Tomcat5.5 heap size is 1024m. I have tried to read the dummy .xlsx file with the amount of rows I am expecting. And it throws OOM..

Comment: And how big is the dummy file on disk?

Comment: Just having a quick Google, people complain about the same exception when using that framework on files as small as 4 - 6 MB with 1GB JVM. Seems like the memory footprint is a general issue with it. Possible solution would be to build an Excel workbook manually with your macros m write your data to CSV as previously suggested and import the CSV into your workbook with the macros. You could even write a macro to automate the import.

Comment: I think that will help me out. But I am aware of writing the data to CSV. But can you help me out of how to import CSV to the workbook? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could obviously do it manually, but assuming you want to automate it I would suggest using Visual Studio Tools for Office (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398242.aspx) you can write a handler for the workbook open event which would automatically look for a CSV in a particular location and give you the handle to import the data as you see fit, but using C# rather than Java (they're not that different if you haven't used C# before). Alternatively you could make the handler callable by the user (button or menu item) and allow them to select the relevant file.

Comment: Thansk a lot.. :) I wish this should work. I will try and keep posted.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems long time ago attempting to write from R to an excel file (but using XLConnection). 
In the end, I solved by using write.csv and then opening it with Excel and using the botton "Text to column".
It is increadibly fast and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue when my excel was reaching 3000 lines. In my case the main memory related issue with POI Excel generation happens with the style sheet. Following are the things which I removed from my code.

1. Try to use style sheet setting in a row level.
2. If at all you need to set the style sheet for every cell.. avoid setting border for each and every cell.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Use latest Apache POI JAR//And Use SXSSF for streaming or downloading

```
 SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(100); 
            workbook.setCompressTempFiles(true);
            Sheet sh = workbook.createSheet();
            ((SXSSFSheet) sh).setRandomAccessWindowSize(100);
```

//write your logic

```
   response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; 
       filename="+filename+".xlsx");
            workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());
            workbook.close();
            workbook.dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an out of memory issues writing a XSSFWorkbook to a file.
The Suggestions above helped a lot.
See http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api

1. Changing XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
           to SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(-1);
       SXSSFSheet sh = ... to SXSSFSheet sh = ...
       XSSFRow to SXSSFRow
       XSSFCell to SXSSFCell
2. inside the for loop USE sh.flushRows(100); for every 100th row
3. after wb.write(out);
   ADD wb.dispose();